# Data apending into sesame repository

Tags: python, rdf, semantic-web, sesame

I inserted RDF formatted data into Sesame in a repository, but when I try to append some more data into that repository, my previous data is gone and new data is being overwritten into that repository.  What am I doing wrong?

```py
import urllib2
import urllib 
import httplib2


par = {"text": "he is a good boy"}
headers={"Accept" : "application/rdf+xml"}
request = urllib2.Request("http://wit.istc.cnr.it/stlab-tools/fred/?" + urllib.urlencode(par),headers=headers)
contents = urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
print contents

repository = 'good_boy'
graph      = 'http://wit.istc.cnr.it/sentilo-dev/fred/xdot/graphviz_139546518295.gv'

print "Loading into Sesame"
params = { 'context': '<' + graph + '>' }
endpoint = "http://localhost:3030/openrdf-sesame/repositories/%s/statements?%s" % (repository, urllib.urlencode(params))
(response, content) = httplib2.Http().request(endpoint, 'PUT',
body=contents, headers={ 'content-type': 'application/rdf+xml' })
print "Response %s" % response.status
print content
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22574236/appending-data-to-a-repository . If you are the same person: don't open a new question when you have additional information. Instead, *edit your question* to add the necessary details.

Comment: JeenBroekstra , yes its my question.Sorry i am new to stackoverflow so i dont know the edit feature .
here is my code so please give me information regarding it

Comment: No prob, we were all new once. Just click the 'edit' link on your old question. If you need more info on how this site works, have a look at the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), particularly the section on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: ok i will not make that mistake again, please tell me answer to my question

Comment: Very well we can treat this one as the original and close the old question as a duplicate.

Comment: yes u can close the old one, please answer my question first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you are using a HTTP `PUT` request, instead of a `POST` request, to add your data to the Sesame repository.

A `PUT` request overwrites existing data, it is a replace (rather than append) operation. See the [Sesame REST protocol documentation](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/system.docbook?view#chapter-http-protocol), particularly the section on [adding statements](http://openrdf.callimachus.net/sesame/2.7/docs/system.docbook?view#repository-statements), for details.